# \implies from the above line

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In a multi-line equations like below, what is the proper mathematical symbol to denote “from the above line it follows that ...”?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \overline{x} = \frac{4(1+r+r^2)}{3\pi(1+r)} &= r\\
    4(1+r+r^2) &= 3r\pi(1+r)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Or is it simply putting `\implies` at the start of each such line?

Comment: Are you sure that's a TeX question? Sounds for me like math (maybe even opinion-based).

Comment: `\therefore` or `\implies`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're after the `\ArrowBetweenLines` from `mathtools`. Personally, I prefer a simple `\shortintertext`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
                                 & & \overline{x} = \frac{4(1+r+r²)}{3π(1+r)} & = r \\
  \ArrowBetweenLines[\Downarrow] & & 4(1+r+r²) & = 3rπ(1+r)
\end{alignat*}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \overline{x} = \frac{4(1+r+r²)}{3π(1+r)} & = r & & \\
  \ArrowBetweenLines*[\Downarrow]4(1+r+r²) & = 3rπ(1+r) & &
\end{alignat*}
\begin{align*}
  \overline{x} = \frac{4(1+r+r²)}{3π(1+r)} & = r \\
  \shortintertext{whence}
  (1+r+r²) & = 3rπ(1+r)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]